# How to bucket pandas timeseries and apply complex groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a timeseries dataframe like below

```
ts_ms            a.       b.       c.       x.    y.    z
1614772770705.   10.      10.      4.       1     2     3
1614772770800.   10.      10.      2.       1     2     4
1614772770750.   10.      5.       4.       1     2     3
```

I need to create 5 min buckets and then apply the dataframe equivalent of the SQL below

```
select sum(x), sum(y), sum(z)
group by a, b, c
```

What I have so far is

```
#convert to datetimes 
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])
# create bucket
df.set_index('ts_date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min'))
```

But I am not sure how to apply the SQL equivalent to this dataframe after this point.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

If need grouping by `5Min` together by `a,b,c` columns use one [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])
df1 = df.groupby(['a','b','c',pd.Grouper(freq='5Min',key='ts_date')])[["x", "y", "z"]].sum()

print (df1)
                                   x   y   z
a    b    c   ts_date                       
10.0 5.0  4.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  7   8   9
              1970-01-01 00:45:00  7   8   9
     10.0 2.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  8  10  12
          4.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  2   4   6
```

Or is possible use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `5Min`:

```
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])

df2 = df.set_index('ts_date').groupby(['a','b','c'])[["x", "y", "z"]].resample('5Min').sum()
print (df2)
                                   x   y   z
a    b    c   ts_date                       
10.0 5.0  4.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  7   8   9
              1970-01-01 00:30:00  0   0   0
              1970-01-01 00:35:00  0   0   0
              1970-01-01 00:40:00  0   0   0
              1970-01-01 00:45:00  7   8   9
     10.0 2.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  8  10  12
          4.0 1970-01-01 00:25:00  2   4   6
```

Comment: in your second solution where is the `sum`?

Comment: @nad Yes, it is aggregate with sum.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
# data.csv
ts_ms,a,b,c,x,y,z
1614772770705.,10.,10.,4.,1,2,3
1614772770800.,10.,10.,2.,4,5,6
1614772770750.,10.,5.,4.,7,8,9
1614772770805.,10.,10.,4.,1,2,3
1614772770900.,10.,10.,2.,4,5,6
2714772770850.,10.,5.,4.,7,8,9
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def func(grp):
    return grp.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min'))[["x", "y", "z"]].sum()

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])
df.set_index('ts_date', inplace=True)
df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).apply(func)
```

Outputs:

```
                                                x   y   z
a       b       c       ts_date             
10.0    5.0     4.0     1970-01-01 00:25:00     7   8   9
                        1970-01-01 00:30:00     0   0   0
                        1970-01-01 00:35:00     0   0   0
                        1970-01-01 00:40:00     0   0   0
                        1970-01-01 00:45:00     7   8   9
        10.0    2.0     1970-01-01 00:25:00     8   10  12
                4.0     1970-01-01 00:25:00     2   4   6
```